# Question on Rudin sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, advice, learning

In baby Rudin, Rudin shows that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{p} = 1.$$

In the proof of limit he tries to prove that the limit is $1$. So he takes $x_n = \sqrt[n]{p} - 1$.

I have never noticed this before, but I could have tried to prove the limit for any $n \neq 1$ (and obviously it wouldn't hold). But in the process of proving that the limit is $1$, did he have some special insight that $\lim_{n \to \infty} = 1$? My question becomes clearer below: He now says that by the binomial theorem, $$0 < 1 + nx_n \leq (1 + x_n)^n = p$$

**But how in the world, as an undergraduate, am I supposed to pull that out of my nearly-empty math toolbox?** I never even knew such a technique existed. In fact, with Rudin, he uses many esoteric proofs (that all work out, anyway) and I have no idea what could have caused him to realize that is the way (in this case, using the binomial theorem) to prove such a sequence.

I noticed indeed that he just selected a sequence that is smaller than $p$ and show by the squeeze theorem of upper and lower limits that $x_n \to 0$. This is a red herring.

But here is what he specifically wrote:

$$0 < x_n < \frac{p - 1}{n}$$

But $p = (1 + x_n)^n$, so how do we know indeed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{p} = 1$??

**My main concern is**, how can I learn the methods to prove sequences and series without being inefficient? Should I just look at many solutions to limits of sequences, go hard and kill myself at the problems anyway, or keep reading (which is very slow for me, at perhaps an hour a page)?

Comment: Have you read 'How to solve it' by Polya?.
This is just a book recomendation passing by..., but I believe it may help you with differents way to study the proofs and answer the question 'how did he knew this was the right way?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log trick is always helpful, when your base is non-negative:

$p^{1/n}=e^{(1/n)lnp}$. Now, $lnp$ is fixed, and $(1/n) \rightarrow 0$ , so you can find

an  $M$ , so that for $n>M$ , $\frac {1}{n}<\frac{1}{\epsilon(lnp)}$ ....

EDIT: Another useful trick is that of sequential continuity, which works on the Reals:
the idea is : given a sequence $x_n $ with $x_n \rightarrow x$ , and $f$ is continuous, it follows that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ . In this particular case, the function $x^a$ is continuous. You can then say, for $x^{1/n}:$ $Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x^{1/n}=e^{Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(1/n)}=e^0=1}.$ You can also get a lot of mileage out of this one.

Comment: I like this one the most! How often does it work?

Comment: When you have a non-negative base $a$, you always have that $a^x$=$e^{xlna}$, and then you know the behavior of $e^x$, so it is often easy to manipulate. Let me edit another trick that is often useful.

Comment: I'm not sure how the **EDIT** example holds? (at the very end) Please walk me through it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: basically, continuity allows you to interchange limits and function values, in the sense that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f( x_n)=f(lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(x_n))$ . For example, if you have $x_n=1/n$ , and f is continuous, then $f(1/n) \rightarrow f(0)$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another avenue.  Suppose $p \ge 1$. Then by the Geometric Series Theorem,
$$\root{n}\of{p} - 1 = {p- 1\over \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p^{k/n}}\le {p-1\over n}. $$
Hence $\root{n}\of {p} \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.  If $0 < p < 1$, you can apply this result to $1/p$.

Comment: Hey I'm trying to convert the series at the denominator and I got $$\frac{p^{\frac{k+1}{n}}}{p^{\frac{k}{n}}(1 - {p^{\frac{k}{n}}})}.$$ Now what?

Comment: All of the terms are $\ge 1$.  So the sum is bounded below by $n$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: It's unclear to me. Please clarify?

Comment: Note I said $p\ge 1$.  In this case $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p^{k/n}\ge \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1\ge n$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is the following: recall that 
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{c_n} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{c_n} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n},$$
where $c_n > 0.$ Then you obtain the desired result for the constant sequence $c_n \equiv p.$